# Typings seems utterly messed up after converting project from angular 2 to angular 5

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript-typings

I am having problems compiling the project after upgrading to angular 5. The project fails to compile probably because typing is messed up. The project previously used typings, but I've tried to install this in the more modern way using @types but it doesn't fix it either.

The following is the current package.json:

```
{
    "name": "my-app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "author": "geewhizbang",
    "description": "Package for my-app",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
        "tsc": "tsc",
        "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
        "lite": "lite-server",
        "build": "npm run clean && tsc",
        "test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
        "posttest": "node_modules/.bin/remap-istanbul -i coverage/coverage-final.json -o coverage -t html",
        "coverage": "http-server -c-1 -o -p 9875 ./coverage"
    },
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^5.2.10",
        "@angular/common": "^5.2.10",
        "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.10",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.10",
        "@angular/core": "^5.2.10",
        "@angular/forms": "^5.2.10",
        "@angular/http": "^5.2.10",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.10",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.10",
        "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.10",
        "@angular/router": "^5.2.10",
        "@angular/upgrade": "2.3.0-rc.0",
        "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
        "remap-istanbul": "^0.8.4",
        "rxjs": "5.0.0-rc.4",
        "systemjs": "0.19.40",
        "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/angular": "^1.6.43",
        "@types/angular-mocks": "^1.5.11",
        "@types/angular-route": "^1.3.5",
        "@types/angularlocalstorage": "^0.1.32",
        "@types/express": "^4.11.1",
        "@types/express-serve-static-core": "^4.11.1",
        "@types/gulp": "^4.0.5",
        "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.36",
        "@types/jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "@types/mime": "^2.0.0",
        "@types/node": "^6.0.106",
        "@types/q": "^1.5.0",
        "@types/serve-static": "^1.13.1",
        "babel-core": "^6.23.1",
        "browserify": "^14.1.0",
        "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
        "compress": "^0.99.0",
        "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
        "del": "^2.2.2",
        "gulp": "^3.9.1",
        "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
        "gulp-imagemin": "^3.1.1",
        "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.4.1",
        "gulp-typescript": "^3.1.5",
        "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.1",
        "http-server": "^0.9.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
        "karma": "^1.3.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
        "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
        "lodash": "^4.16.4",
        "mangle": "^1.1.3",
        "protractor": "~4.0.14",
        "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
        "systemjs-builder": "^0.16.3",
        "tslint": "^3.15.1",
        "typescript": "^2.8.3",
        "uglifyjs": "^2.4.10"
    },
    "repository": {}
}
```

The above file was upgraded from the original by using npm install:

```
npm install @angular/common@latest @angular/compiler@latest @angular/compiler-cli@latest @angular/core@latest @angular/forms@latest @angular/http@latest @angular/platform-browser@latest @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@latest @angular/platform-server@latest @angular/router@latest @angular/animations@latest typescript@latest --save
```

But it now fails to compile because types are messed up somehow.

The following is the current tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "system",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": false, // make this false for minification
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noStrictGenericChecks": true,
        "outFile": "./app/app.min.js", // uncomment this line for minification
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ]
    },
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typings",
        //comment out these two lines for jasmine
        "./app/**/*.spec.ts",
        "./app/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

I tried to follow what this developer suggested in converting to @types:

https://georgedyrra.com/2017/06/04/migrating-from-typings-to-npm-types/

Comment: Do yourself a favor, and use angular CLI. You're using typings for AngularJS, although you're using Angular. You don't need any separate typing for Angular, since it's written in TypeScript and thus comes with its own typings directly.

Comment: This may be good advice JB Nizet. I prefer simpler solutions. So are you saying that I can remove all the types or just the angular ones and add the angular/cli to the package?

Comment: My advice would be to start a brand new angular-cli project from scratch, as explained in its documentation, and then move your existing code to that clean angular-cli project.

Answer (score 0):

In the above package.json I removed es6-shim and angular upgrade. It also didn't help that I had renamed the obsolete typings folder instead of just deleting it. NPM compiles everything past the root, it apparently doesn't care about folder names like I thought.

It actually is a good example of how to upgrade. Using npm install to do the latest did a better job than all the manual editing I had done on previous attempts.

Comment: I was able to eliminate all of these types:

"@types/angular": "^1.6.43",
"@types/angular-mocks": "^1.5.11",
"@types/angular-route": "^1.3.5",
"@types/angularlocalstorage": "^0.1.32",

without any problems. I'm already using angular-cli, so they are not necessary.